# change day by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, days

I want that each time I'm clicking on button that I see the **Next** day from day array list

The only way that I could get an answer is Math.random() to have different result each time I am clicking on button, but I want that show me  the next day each time I am clicking on it.

```js
function day() {
  var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
}
```

```html
<button onclick='day()'>Click to see</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Add a variable storing the current array index. When the button is clicked, increment the index, then use it to grab the day from the array. Note that using variables is a basic programming concept. So basic you won't even find tutorials for it. Please make sure to learn the basic mechanisms of programming before posting here.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640494/295783) for a script using today as a start and recommended eventListener

Comment: @mplungjan - Thank you sir that helps me alot to learn new things .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an array representing the days in the week while also keep an index to show the current day `current`.

On each click you will increment `current` value. The `innerHtml` value will be the current index (the `%` is being added to prevent out of bounce)

```js
var days =['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];
let current = 0;
function day(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[current++ % days.length];
}
```

```html
<button onclick='day()'>Click to see</button>
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe start at Sunday like JS does?

Comment: @ran-turner -  That was useful information thank you for it ,I'm beginner in this programming language ,I have 1 more question if i want that start from today i guess i need to use  getDay() , Am i right ?

Comment: @mplungjan  -  If i want that start from today i guess i need to use getDay() , Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() *7); //if you want always start from 'Monday' you can use 0 as startIndex
let days =['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
function day(){      
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[index];
  index = (index+1)%7     
}
```

```html
<button onclick='day()'>Click to see</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start from today you can use getDay which starts on Sunday

```js
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
let day = new Date().getDay(); //today
document.getElementById('addDay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[day++ % 7]; // move the ++ to ++day to show tomorrow on first click
})
```

```html
<button id="addDay" type="button">Click to see</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```